# VirtualBox does not start virtual machine in 'docker-machine create'

Tags: docker, virtualbox, docker-machine, macos-high-sierra

I am following the [docker tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part4/#create-a-cluster) and at Part 4: Swarms. After entering `docker-machine create --driver virtualbox myvm1`, I can see that the newly created docker-machine is in 'Stopped' STATE. If I do `docker-machine restart myvm1`, I get the following error including `VBoxManage: error: Failed to create the host-only adapter`:

```
(tfvm1) Progress state: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
(tfvm1) VBoxManage: error: Failed to create the host-only adapter
(tfvm1) VBoxManage: error: VBoxNetAdpCtl: Error while adding new interface: failed to open /dev/vboxnetctl: No such file or directory
(tfvm1) VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component HostNetworkInterfaceWrap, interface IHostNetworkInterface
(tfvm1) VBoxManage: error: Context: "RTEXITCODE handleCreate(HandlerArg *)" at line 94 of file VBoxManageHostonly.cpp
(tfvm1) 
(tfvm1) This is a known VirtualBox bug. Let's try to recover anyway...
Error setting up host only network on machine start: The host-only adapter we just created is not visible. This is a well known VirtualBox bug. You might want to uninstall it and reinstall at least version 5.0.12 that is is supposed to fix this issue
```

The VirtualBox version [`vboxmanage --version`] is `5.2.6r120293`; I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling VirtualBox anyway. Also tried rebooting my macOS High Sierra, and installing Java v8 as suggested by [this link](https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/4066), none made a difference.

If I try to start the VM in VirtualBox GUI, I get this error about 'VERR_VM_DRIVER_NOT_INSTALLED (-1908)', similar to issues in [this link](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=84092).

I am one of the several users on the Mac. I have also tried running 'docker-machine create --driver virtualbox myvm1' as a root user, and the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I reverted back to Virtualbox 5.1.28 to get docker-machine to work again